# bash string split and concatenate

Tags: bash

I have hundreds files need to loop through for an analysis using a bash script. One step I need to do is to split a long string and cat it as an output name. For example, suppose I have one string such like:

```
5018.a.Radiation_Induced_Lymphoma.Tumor__p53+_-.SL200300_SL200300.exome_1tier.mm10.kapa_re_cap_v6_3utr.final.bam
```

What I wanted is to rename it as two output file names such as:

```
5018.a.Radiation_Induced_Lymphoma.Tumor__p53+_-.SL200300_SL200300.exome_1tier.mm10.kapa_re_cap_v6_3utr.final_R1.fastq
5018.a.Radiation_Induced_Lymphoma.Tumor__p53+_-.SL200300_SL200300.exome_1tier.mm10.kapa_re_cap_v6_3utr.final_R2.fastq
```

The only changes are removing `.bam` from the original and `cat` `_R1.fastq` and `_R2_fastq`. Does somebody know how to realize it using bash commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
somefile=blahblahblah.final.bam
foo "$somefile" "${somefile%.*}_R1.fastq" "${somefile%.*}_R2.fastq"
```